# Scala Ambiguous reference with same signature and argument types

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, scala-java-interop

How does Scala shows an ambiguous reference error, where both alternatives have the same signature? How to overcome it?

Code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.test

val stringSerializer = new StringSerializer
val stringFactory: ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String] =
    new ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String](
      eventTopic, stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
val testKey : String = ""
val testVal : String = ""
val recordString : ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = 
    stringFactory.create(testKey, testVal)
```

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method create in class ConsumerRecordFactory of type (x$1: String, x$2: String)org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]
[error] and  method create in class ConsumerRecordFactory of type (x$1: String, x$2: String)org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]
[error] match argument types (String,String) and expected result type org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]
[error]     val recordString : ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = stringFactory.create(testKey, testVal)
```

As you can see, both methods have the same signature. This does not happen when using CustomerFactory of other types, namely custom case class types for which I have custom serializers for (and not the provided StringSerializer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the ambiguous methods issue, you should follow following approach.

1. Create an instance of ConsumerRecordFactory with KeySerializer and ValueSerializer
2. Pass the topic in ConsumerRecord followed by Key and value.

Example :

```
val stringSerializer = new StringSerializer
val stringFactory: ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String] =
    new ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String](
      stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
val testKey : String = ""
val testVal : String = ""
val recordString : ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = 
    stringFactory.create(eventTopic, testKey, testVal)
```

Another option is passing Key and Value as bytearray.

```
val stringFactory: ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String] =
    new ConsumerRecordFactory[String, String](
      eventTopic, stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
val testKey : String = ""
val testVal : String = ""
val recordString : ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = 
    stringFactory.create(testKey.getBytes, testVal.getBytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

So, in the class ConsumerFactory, there are a method `create(final K key, final V value)` and another one `create(final String topicName, final V value)`. 
Since the first K can be matched by a String, it is an ambiguous reference. However, since it is not the original types in the method signature that are shown in the error but the *effective* ones, the message is somewhat confusing.
This is a specifity of this API and not of Scala or Scala-Java interop.

My solution in this case was to provide key and value as ByteArray, the ultimate type Kafka uses as source type:

```
val byteArraySerializer = new ByteArraySerializer
val stringFactory: ConsumerRecordFactory[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] =
    new ConsumerRecordFactory[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](
      eventTopic, byteArraySerializer, byteArraySerializer)
val recordString : ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = 
    stringFactory.create(testKey.getBytes, testVal.getBytes)
```

The solution provided by @nishu-tayal also works, though it forces you to specify the topic every time. A matter of taste here, I suppose.